# jquery cannot get button using id selector when use load method

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-load

I have a page named loop.php and have two radio buttons A & B, when A is checked then I load a.html and when B is checked load b.html.

loop.php (most important part)

```
<div>
    <input id="radio_one" type="radio" value="radio_one" />&nbsp;tpl_one&nbsp;
    <input id="radio_two" type="radio" value="radio_two" />&nbsp;tpl_two

    <!--template1-->
    <div id="tpl_one"></div>
    <!-- template 1 end-->

    <!-- template2 -->
    <div id="tpl_two"></div>
    <!--template 2 end-->
</div>
```

a.html

```
<div>
    <input type="button" id="tpl_one_btn" name="" value="in tpl one"/>
</div>
```

b.html

```
<div>
    <input type="button" id="tpl_two_btn" name="" value="in tpl two"/>
</div>
```

I am using jquery-1.9, and I can easily implements my requirements. All of the jquery code are in a file whose name is `op.js`

```
 $(function(){
   $("#radio_one").click(function(){
       $("#tpl_two").hide();
       $("#tpl_one").show();
       $("#tpl_one").load('a.html');
   });

   $("#radio_two").click(function(){
      $("#tpl_one").hide();
      $("#tpl_two").show();
      $("#tpl_two").load('b.html');
   });
 });
```

Everything is ok now, I can do almost everything, but things chang bad when I want to work with buttons on a.html & b.html.

In op.js I want to fire an event when I click the button in a.html

```
$("#tpl_one_btn").click(function(){
    console.log('button in a.html');
});
```

Nothing happend, that it's to say I don't get the button via button's id `$("#tpl_one_btn")`

I realized that maybe the problem is because of `load` method, so I have an experiment, I move the button to loop.php that it is to say, I don't load a button via a jQuery Ajax function. And this time the above code go well.

Why has this happened when I use load method? Why I cannot get the button via jQuery id selector?

If I want to use load method, how can I got the button using jQuery id selector?

Comment: asked hundred times a week... BTW, IDs should be unique on context page, hope its your case

Comment: @roasted thanks, IDs are unique

Comment: There's also hundred duplicates :(

Comment: So, see @pXL's answer it is what you are looking for even you should use closest static container,  instead of document but both will work

Comment: You can load the page contents using `when` and `then` methods to ensure the button is in the page, afterwards bind the events to the button.

Comment: @senyorToni oh, I don't know when or then method in jquery, can I find it in jquery's doc? Thanks.

Comment: @diligent yes http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use event delegation (*as you are adding your button dynamically*)

```
$(document.body).on('click',"#tpl_one_btn",function(){
    console.log('button in a.html');
});
```

- http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: thanks, but why I use got this problem when I use load mehtod, just because it's an ajax method and the document in a.html are not loaded immediately?

Comment: find a useful link, thanks man. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009364/jquery-load-makes-content-not-clickable-after-load?rq=1

Comment: @diligent  that is because, your button isn't there when you are binding click event i.e on page load,(_events are bound only if element is in DOM, unless you use event delegation_), , You can find detailed explaination on the link in my answer